# Anabolic Effects of Beta-Ecdysterone

Tags: muscle, steroids

Should one expect similar gains in muscle mass from supplementing beta-ecdysteroid to anabolic steroids like Nerobol or Methylandrostenediol? From the research I have done so far it is clear that beta-ecdysteroid has anabolic properties (e.g. [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4447764/)), but how does the scale of muscle mass gain compare? [This study](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02524596) would seem to show very similar effects on mass gain, but I cant' seem to find a straight and direct answer to this question.